# Eigenvalues of Frobenius in $l$-adic cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, l-adic-sheaves

Let $X_0$ be a smooth projective variety over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$. Let $X$ be the corresponding variety over the algebraic closure $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_q$. Let $Fr_q\colon X\to X$ be the geometric Frobenius.

**Is it true that the eigenvalues of $Fr_q$ on $H^i(X,\mathbb{Q}_l)$ ($l\ne char(\mathbb{F}_q)$) are algebraic integers independent of $l$? Is the same true if $X_0$ is not necessarily smooth and projective?**

A reference would be helpful.

**Remark.** I know that in the smooth projective case the eigenvalues are algebraic numbers (I do not know if they are integers).

Sorry if this question is well known to experts, I am not from this field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was proven by Deligne in the smooth projective case [Weil I, Thm. I.6], and later in the smooth proper case [Weil II, Cor. 3.3.9].

In general (already for smooth *quasi*-projective varieties), we don't even know whether $\dim H^i(X_{\text{ét}},\mathbf Q_\ell)$ is independent of $\ell$. See for instance [Katz, p. 28, 2(a)] or [Illusie, 3.5(c)]. I also wrote a paper on this [vDdB] that may contain some more references.

---

**References.**

[Weil I]  P. Deligne, [*La conjecture de Weil. I*](http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1974__43__273_0/). Publ. Math. Inst. Hautes Étud. Sci. **43**, p. 273-307 (1973). [ZBL0287.14001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0287.14001).

[Weil II]  P. Deligne, [*La conjecture de Weil. II*](http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1980__52__137_0/), Publ. Math. Inst. Hautes Étud. Sci. **52**, p. 137-252 (1980). [ZBL0456.14014](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0456.14014).

[Katz]  N. M. Katz, *Review of $\ell$-adic cohomology*. In: [Motives](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/pspum/055.1). Proc. Symp. Pure Math. **55**.1, p. 21-30 (1994). [ZBL0817.14006](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0817.14006).

[Illusie]  L. Illusie, [*Miscellany on traces in $\ell$-adic cohomology: a survey*](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11537-006-0504-3). Jpn. J. Math. (3) **1**.1, p. 107-136 (2006). [ZBL1156.14309](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1156.14309).

[vDdB]  R. van Dobben de Bruyn, [*The equivalence of several conjectures on independence of $\ell$*](https://doi.org/10.46298/epiga.2020.volume4.5570). Épijournal de Géom. Algébr. **4**, Article No. 16 (2020). [ZBL1460.14053](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1460.14053).

Comment: That the eigenvalues are algebraic integers had been proved by Deligne before the proof of the Weil conjectures: see Corollary 5.5.3 of Exposé XXI in SGA 7. You don't need smoothness nor projectivity if you consider cohomology with proper support.

Comment: @abx ah, I don't think I knew that. Thanks for the pointer!